# Too many wrong entries pinescript in strategy (simple ema)

Tags: pine-script

my script is just setting too many entries, idk how to explain it, it is wrong entries. look at this

[image: Trading view chart]

it is really confusing and the code is verryyy simple

```cs
//@version=4
strategy("Simple ema")
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ema(close,200)
long = ema50 < ema200
short = ema200 > ema50

strategy.entry("Long", long, 1, when=long)
strategy.entry("Short", short, 1, when=short)
strategy.close("Long", when=short)
strategy.close("Short", when=long)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will open a long position whenever ema50 is less than ema200 and open a short position whenever ema200 is greater than ema50.

You probably want to use the `crossover` and `crossunder` functions.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Simple ema")
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ema(close,200)
long = crossunder(ema50, ema200)
short = crossover(ema200, ema50)

strategy.entry("Long", long, 1, when=long)
strategy.entry("Short", short, 1, when=short)
strategy.close("Long", when=short)
strategy.close("Short", when=long)
```